# converting const void* pointer to specific class pointer

Tags: c++

I have function declaration as below

```
void func1(const void& * pThis) {
    MyClass* pMyClass = static_cast<MyClass*>(pThis);    //....I use PMyClass pointer.
}
```

I am getting error cannot convert `const void*` to `MyClass*`

How to do this step?

Comment: Do you mean to be dropping the `const` qualifier as part of the cast? If so, you'll also need a `const_cast`; otherwise, you'll need to cast to a `const MyClass *` instead...

Comment: `const void& * pThis` should not even compile, because pointer-to-reference is not allowed : http://ideone.com/XAzWA ... in this case, there is yet another problem: `void&` doesn't even make sense.

Comment: A `const void *` points to memory that should not be modified.

A void * (non-const) points to memory that could be modified (but not via the void *; you'd have to cast it first).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can

```
MyClass* pMyClass = const_cast<MyClass*>( static_cast<const MyClass*>(pThis) );
```

But this awful syntax is the hint: why then the function has a const argument, wouldn't you want it to be like

```
void func1(void * pThis) {
```

Of course, you can take a shortcut using C-style cast:

```
MyClass* pMyClass = (MyClass*)pThis;
```

but I would fix the design instead if possible.

Comment: Most importantly, though, if the pointer points to an object that is actually `const`, then accessing it in a non-const way is undefined behaviour. `const_cast` should be used only in extremely specific situations, and never light-heartedly.

Answer (score 4):

The `const` is the problem. It can't be cast away using `static_cast`. Given you're casting it into a non-const `MyClass`, there's no use in accepting a const argument anyway. You can use `const_cast` to remove the const-ness, but that would be bad - your method declares it is not going to change the argument, but it is in fact changing it.